# Retrieve photos from firebase storage SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem since yesterday morning but I can't figure it out how can I resolve this issue.

I'm having a table view which is using prototype cells, 2 labels and 1 photo. For the labels I used Firestore and for the picture firebase storage.

The problems is that the only way I know how to retrieve photos from my firebase storage is this code

```
 
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let ref = storageRef.child("Mancare/Mancare3.jpg")
        testImage.sd_setImage(with: ref)
```

I want to retrieve the photos into my table view, but I do not know how can I can accomplish that.

This is what im using for retrieving the labels with Firestore . I'll paste only the necessary parts of the code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewTest.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let ref = storageRef.child("Mancare/Mancare3.jpg")
        
        let label = labels[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelTest.text = label.firstLabel
        cell.labelLaba.text = label.secondLabel
      
        
        
        return cell
        
        
    }

func getDatabaseRecords() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        labels = []  //  Empty the array
        db.collection("labels").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Labels(
                        firstLabel: data["firstLabel"] as! String,
                        secondLabel: data["secondLabel"] as! String)
                        
                        
                        
                    self.labels
                        .append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableViewTest.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I declared the labels:

```
struct Labels {
    let firstLabel: String
    let secondLabel: String
   
  
}

 var labels: [Labels] = []
```

If someone can help me , ill be forever grateful . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you need to fix your model so it can help you. Add the bucket name to the model like this:

```
Struct Labels {
    let firstLabel: String
    let secondLabel: String
    let photoKey: String // This will store the bucket name for this `Labels`
}
```

2. Now in your `getDatabaseRecords` change:

```
let newEntry = Labels(firstLabel: data["firstLabel"] as! String,
                      secondLabel: data["secondLabel"] as! String),
                      photoKey: data["photoKey"] as! String) // Added Line
```

3. Then in `cellForRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewTest.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell
    let label = labels[indexPath.row]
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let photoRef = storageRef.child(label.photoKey)
        
    cell.labelTest.text = label.firstLabel
    cell.labelLaba.text = label.secondLabel
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: photoRef) // Assuming the image view in your cell is named this
      
    return cell
}
```

4. Last, make sure your document structure matches the new `Labels` Model in the firebase console, and you have images as well in the root of your storage that match with all the `photoKey`s. Btw, `Labels` is not a very good model name, I just went with it for consistency

Comment: It worked well , thank you very very much. Off topic, another question related to this, when I run the app, I only have row with datas. how can I make different rows with different pictures, labels, etc :). https://imgur.com/U2GemAg - tableview

Comment: You'd just add them to your database the same way you added the first one, then add the photos for them as well. It should automatically populate in your TableView

Comment: So, I just need to add more documents in my collection. Is worked, thank u . Have a good day :)